# Error in Using Practical_seq2seq with tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm newbie and I really need you're help in using tensorflow in python.

I want to build chatbot with sequence to sequence by using this [link in github](https://github.com/suriyadeepan/practical_seq2seq). But when I started to run this code `python 03-Twitter-chatbot.py` (after downloading then extracting datasets and [read the related article](http://suriyadeepan.github.io/2016-12-31-practical-seq2seq/)) the program didn't run. And shows these the error message:

```
<log> Building Graph Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "03-Twitter-chatbot.py", line 33, in <module>
    num_layers=3
  File "D:\Temporary\abang nitip\Directory\practical_seq2seq-master\seq2seq_wrapper.py", line 79, in __init__    __graph__()
  File "D:\Temporary\abang nitip\Directory\practical_seq2seq-master\seq2seq_wrapper.py", line 45, in __graph__    basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'core_rnn_cell'
```

I wonder what happen, I started to run another [code](https://github.com/pender/chatbot-rnn) the error is different it's say that *my tensorflow cannot import basic_rnn or seq2seq*. Then I checked my tensorflow with running this code in cmd:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

After typing `sess = tf.Session()` there is a message like this:

```
2017-07-18 13:46:37.730648: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-18 13:46:37.731648: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I don't know how to solve this, I just guess *maybe my tensorflow didn't running well*. I use tensorflow in my pc with spesification **Windows 7 Ultimate -  64 bit, Python 3.5.2**.

Please help me to overcome this.
And I am very sorry for my bad english

Comment: I had this issue few days ago. Your tensorflow version is probably 1.0
and the code was written for earlier versions.here 
https://github.com/pender/chatbot-rnn/issues/6 is the github link to the issue and updated code.

Comment: thank you @venky__ I just try by replacing code in model.py on that link but still cannot run because tensorflow cannot recognize 'core_rnn_cell'

Answer (score 0):

As Venky said, This is a backward-compatibility issue.

<del>If you just want to make it work, you should downgrade to tensorflow 0.12.0 . The [github project](https://github.com/suriyadeepan/practical_seq2seq) you share already specified the tensowflow version(0.12) it based on. You can do this with a simple</del>

`pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==0.12`

If you want learn more details of seq2seq in tensorflow, [this current google official seq2seq tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt) may be a better choice. The official tutorial just released several days ago and introduce some new tf features like 'dynamic_rnn'.

## Update

As said in comment,the git repo have updated the code without update the compatibility info which means It's not clear what is the right tf version you need. You should try a recent tensorflow version(1.1 or 1.2) .

Comment: Hello there, thank you for answering, but the error still same
`<log> Building Graph Traceback (most recent call last):
File "03-Twitter-chatbot.py", line 33, in <module>
    num_layers=3
File "D:\Temporary\abang nitip\Directory\practical_seq2seq-master\seq2seq_wrapper.py", line 79, in __init__    __graph__()
File "D:\Temporary\abang nitip\Directory\practical_seq2seq-master\seq2seq_wrapper.py", line 45, in __graph__    basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'core_rnn_cell'`

is it because I use windows?

Comment: Hi, Ron. This is not a a windows issue. I checked the git repo again and found that someone have updated the code in April without update the compatibility info which means It's not clear what is the right tf version you need. You should try a recent tensorflow version(1.1 or 1.2) . Sorry for my misleading answer, I will update it after you solve this question. By the way, which version were you use when you first ask this question?

Comment: Also,  Messages like "The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations." are not error. They are just warnings that tells you can ignore at the point.

Comment: hello @hsc I'm already following your advice, and it's work but just in my pc, when my CPU try to train that it's really takes a long time and we have power problem here. So I've tried to use my Campus Computer, and following your instruction and it didn't work, it's said an error like cannot save a `checkpoint` or something, please help

Comment: The checkpoint issue may caused by wrong file path. Please give me more detail to investigate.
If my answer helps, could you mark my answer as solution. I will appreciate it.